# Applications of Linear Transformation in Biological Science

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, biology

I am looking for an application of linear transformation (reflection, shear, compression etc...) in biology.

If anyone knows of a specific bilogy field these transformation may apply to and in what way that would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Support vector machines in machine learning applied to genomics?

Comment: Cryo electron microscopy uses some linear algebra. Also see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571109/any-application-of-vector-spaces-in-biology-or-biotechnology?rq=1